# Extract values from different thread groups and then pass values across different thread groups

Tags: jmeter

I am currently trying to extract 10 different ids(each request will generate a different id) then i am trying to use those 10 different ids in the next thread group.

The way i am doing this is by first using a HTTP request inside a simple controller then i am using a thread group and using a module controller.

First i extract the id from the response and creating a variable like this:

Then i am setting property name like:

```
${__setProperty(loginassistant_${__threadNum},${loginassistant},)}
```

Then i am using thread group and inside a thread group i am using a module controller with 10 threads

then in the next request i am reading it similarly:

```
${__P(loginassistant_${__threadNum},)}
```

But unfortunately in all my requests(10) it is using the same id generated from the first thread group. However, i would to see 10 different ids being used to each 10 of the other requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How many threads does your Thread Group which executes `Journey Steps` have? If its only one - you will have only one ID generated as JMeter properties are global.
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and the following Groovy code (it's equivalent of your functions calls)

   ```
    props.put('loginassistant_' + (ctx.getThreadNum() + 1), vars.get('loginassistant'))
   ```

   where:

   - `props` is a shorthand for JMeter [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)
   - `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html)
   - `ctx` is for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html)

   See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more details.

   Here is the evidence of the approach working:

   [image]
3. Any reason for not going for [Inter-Thread Communication](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) Plugin?